# Implementing subscriber Pubsubhubbub in python

Tags: python, rss, websub

I have a bunch of Google alerts set up as rss feeds that update in real time. What I want is to be able to store the new data the rss feed is sending out in a database.

After looking around I found [Google](http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/) and [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) both offer hubs that do most of the work for you; however they both require a callback url (obviously). I do have an Apache server running on the machine I'm working off, it already has python enabled so I can run python scripts on my server. However at the moment its only accessible from within my LAN.

What my real question is, what do I do next? I know that in php you would just have a call back file that handles requests but I'm lost as to what to do in python. Would I write a script and give the google/superfeedr services a url to that script? What would be in the script? Specific imports needed?

Also, I just read that if you use XMPP you don't need a callback url. How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the local LAN problem, the most commonly used solution is to use tuneling solutions like [Passageway](https://www.runscope.com/docs/passageway). They will temporarily expose a local port of your machine to the "outer" web.

Now, as for implementation, it's fairly easy to set things up. Python is similar to PHP in the sense that you'll have to write a script that listen on networking connection and then handles the HTTP requests you're getting from Superfeedr or Google. (it looks like you're not familiar with Python, why not stick to PHP then?)

Finally XMPP is a feature that only us (Superfeedr) offer. It solves the problem of exposing local ports because it works behind the firewall.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I decided to go with superfeedr and XMPP. I set up my python script, which is the exact same as this [one](https://github.com/superfeedr/superfeedr-python/blob/master/example.py) apart from the fact I've set it to print the str(event) in the body of my html; on my server and its viewable (just constantly listening) but it doesn't seem to be picking up any events. I tried subscribing to your dummy feed and sending requests using the button but it still doesn't seem to be working. No errors just no functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you please email details to julien@superfeedr.com so we can be more helpful?